# Profile a Thread in Linux System using 'Perf stat'

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, profiling, perf

We know how to count the instructions of a process dynamically over some time using 'perf' :

```
perf stat -p <pid> -- sleep <period>
```

I want to be able to do the same thing on a thread. Assuming a Process with PID 1500 has threads with SPID(TID) 1501, 1502, 1503, and 1504. I want to count each threads instructions using

```
perf stat -p <spid> -- sleep <period>
```

However, when I do so, I get:

```
Performance counter stats for process id '1502':
<not counted> instructions
0.504 seconds time elapsed.

Some events weren't counted. Try disabling NMI watchdog:
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog
perf stat ...
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog
```

I am using perf on Raspberry Pi, Raspbian Jessie. There is no '/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog'. The problem I suspect is that I am trying to profile a Thread ID. I would appreciate if there is a workaround or attribute to the 'perf stat' command to check out thread stats.

Thanks..

Comment: There is --tid option to monitor thread: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-stat.1.html "`-t`, `--tid=<tid>` stat events on existing thread id (comma separated list)". Try again from root user. Does `perf stat ls` or any other command instead of ls work? What is your CPU, exact model of CPU (and of RPi)? Hardware events may not be implemented for this CPU or in this kernel version.

Comment: perf stat --per-thread worked instead.